# Checking Holomorphicity of functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I was checking the Holomorphicity of $f(z) = (z-3)^i$ which I wrote it as $e^{i log(z-3)}$, so as $Log(z-3) $ is holomorphic over $\Bbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,3)$ so is $(z-3)^i$. But I am thinking about $f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{z^3 + 1}$ and $f(z) = \operatorname{Log}(z-2i+1)$?, I thought of using Cauchy Riemann equations to rule out Holomorphic, like if it doesnot satisfy CR eqaution then it is not holomorphic, but it seems it may run into complicated calculations?

EDIT -

Just out of curiosity, I thought of this - As $(z-3)^i$ is holomorphic over $\Bbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,3)$, then what can we say about the Holomorphic nature of $i^{z-3}$, just the positions interchanged!!!

Comment: The following things are good to know:

If $f, g$ are holomorphic, then $f \circ g, f + g, f - g, f \cdot g, \frac{f}{g}$ are holomorphic (in the last case only at the points with $g(x) \neq 0$).

Comment: Great!!!, how about $f^g$ and $g^f$ ?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, the functions are holomorphic because they can be obtained from holomorphic functions using sums, subtractions, multiplications, divisions and composition. Each of these operations preserve being holomorphic.

Comment: How t odeal with the last case of $i^(z-3)$?

Comment: @BAYMAX $i^{z-3}=\exp\bigl((z-3)\log i\bigr)$, for some choice of a logarithm of $i$.

Answer (score 1):

$i^{z-3} = \exp((z-3) \log(i)) $ is holomorphic on all of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: How about $Log(z - b)$, where $b$ is complex, for $b$ real I was writing $C\(-\infty,b)$ but what we should write when $b$ is complex?

Comment: The principal branch of the logarithm $\text{Log}(z)$ has the negative real axis $(-\infty, 0)$ as its branch cut, so $\text{Log}(z-b)$ would have $\{b + t: t \in (-\infty, 0)\}$, i.e. the horizontal half-line extending to the left from $b$.